# Remplazar string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Como puedo remplazar este string por otro independientemente de si el valor es 2 o 4 o 5

```
<font size=\"2\"
```

Ahora lo tengo asi :

```
replacingOccurrences(of: "font size=\"2\"", with: "font size=\"4\"")
```

Pero no siempre llegará un 2 por defecto.

Comment: si el texto no va a cambiar, puedes usar algun tipo de `substring` para cortar el texto y poner tu el `int` que quieras. o usar [tag:regex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es bastante extraño el manejo de cadenas en Swift. Sin embargo, una [respuesta de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3) me ha ayudado mucho. La idea general es la siguiente (para la versión 3 del lenguaje):

```
var cadena = "<font size=\"2\""

let inicio = cadena.index(cadena.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
```

Las cadenas tienen dos índices, en inicial llamado `startIndex` y el final llamado `endIndex`. A partir de ellos, podemos construir índices intermedios haciendo uso de los métodos `index`

Para obtener el índice donde en tu cadena empieza el número, obtenemos el índice final y le restamos 2, esto lo hacemos mediante el parámetro `offsetBy` que puede ser positivo (lo cual quiere decir que nos movemos "a la derecha") o negativo (hacia "la izquierda")

```
let fin = cadena.endIndex
let rango = inicio..<fin
```

creamos un rango usando el operador `..<` , lo cual resulta en un rango exclusivo. También se puede usar el operador `...` para uno inclusivo

```
cadena.replacingCharacters(in: rango, with: "nuevo")
```

lo cual regresa: `"<font size="nuevo"`

El código completo se ve así:

```
import Foundation

var cadena = "<font size=\"2\""
let inicio = cadena.index(cadena.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
let fin = cadena.endIndex
let rango = inicio..<fin

cadena.replacingCharacters(in: rango, with: "nuevo")
```